# How to save structs in array in Solidity?

Tags: struct, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I wrote a very simple smart contract which does the following:

- Declares a struct named Player which has 2 fields: name and goals
- Defines a function which takes as inputs names and goals to create a new instance of the structure
- Stores the new player into an array of players

Here is the code:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
contract MyContract {
    
    // Declare struct
    struct Player {
        string name;
        uint goals;
    }
    
    // Declare array
    Player[] player;
    
    function addPlayer(string calldata _name, uint _goals) external pure{
    
       Player memory player = Player({name:_name, goals:_goals}); // This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
    
       players.push(player); // Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct MyContract.Player memory.
    
    }
    
}
```

My goal is to use the *addPlayer()* function to add players to the *players* array
However the VisualStudio Editor returns an error since it gets confused by the declaration of the *Player* variable which appears to be twice.

Could you please provide a smart and elegant way to achieve my goal please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
contract MyContract {
    
    // Declare struct
    struct Player {
        string name;
        uint goals;
    }
    
    // Declare array
    Player[] players;
    
    function addPlayer(string calldata _name, uint _goals) external {
    
       Player memory player = Player(_name,_goals); // This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
    
       players.push(player); // Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct MyContract.Player memory.
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: your function must not be pure

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Chíp Thảo for leaving the answer with not complete explain :)
Here is continue of explain:
In line 12 you declared an array, `Player[] player`, with name `player` and also in line 16 you declared a variable again with name `player`! better change line 12 into `players`.

Comment: Perfect yeah I don't understand how I can be so dumb haha